# How can I gain adjacency matrix from adjacency list?

Tags: python, graph

Sample Input:

4 7 
1 2
2 3
3 1
4 1
2 2
4 2
4 3
The first line contains two numbers:
n and
m
 - the number of vertices and edges in the graph. Next 
m lines contain two numbers each, the starting and the ending vertex of an edge. Input can contain multiple edges and loops.

I need to print the adjacency matrix in 
n
 lines, each one having 
n zeros or ones: 
0 if there is not edge between the corresponding pair of vertices and  1 if there is an edge.

Sample Output:

0100
0110
1000
1110

Comment: Preferably without using numpy and smth like this

Comment: _Preferably without using numpy and smth like this_ Why is that? In any case, I'm voting to close this. Stack Overflow is not the place to drop off entire problem statements for others to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is a puzzle or homework problem, probably shouldn't just be asking for code without some attempt yourself, but here. You can add the reading in and writing out parts on your own.

```
adjacency_list = [...] #adj list
n = ... #num vertices
m = ... #num edges
adjacency_matrix = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)] # (numpy) = np.zeros((n,n))
for i,j in adjacency_list:
    adjacency_matrix[i][j] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy` you can first start with an array of zeros of size `N` (in this case 4). Then you can use your adjacency list as indices into the adjacency matrix and assign ones to those locations.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> mat = np.zeros((4,4))
>>> edges = np.array([[1,2],[2,3],[3,1],[4,1],[2,2],[4,2],[4,3]])
>>> edges -= 1
>>> mat[edges[:,0], edges[:,1]] = 1
>>> mat
array([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0.]])
```